# Insert SQL with SELECT from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables
Table_A

```
meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value
-----------------------------------------
Incremented | 35 | some_value  | 12345
Incremented | 45 | some_value  | 22345
Incremented | 32 | other_value | 22345
```

Table_B

```
object_id | term_taxonomy_id | term_order
-----------------------------------------
    23    |       53         |     0
    54    |       65         |     0
```

I want to insert in Table_B like this (Table_A.post_id, '5302', 0), so I need just post_id from Table_A, but the ones that have meta_key = some_value and meta_value > lets say 20000, actually this is a unix timestamp

Table_B has these props

```
PRIMARY object_id, term_taxonomy_id
INDEX   term_taxonomy_id
```

I tried this query

```
INSERT INTO Table_B (object_id,term_taxonomy_id) 
SELECT u.post_id , '5302' FROM Table_A u INNER JOIN Table_B o ON  u.post_id = o.object_id WHERE u.meta_key = 'some_value' AND u.meta_value < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
```

And I get this error:

> Error in query (1062): Duplicate entry '4066-5302' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Your sample data would not generate that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be you have already a value insert for these value ( entry '4066-5302')  or could be you select return more then a row
in this case you should use distinct

```
  INSERT INTO Table_B (object_id,term_taxonomy_id) 
  SELECT distinct  u.post_id , '5302' 
  FROM Table_A u 
  INNER JOIN Table_B o ON  u.post_id = o.object_id 
    AND  u.meta_key = 'some_value' AND u.meta_value < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the primary key for `Table_B`?

Check if the result from SELECT query already exists in `Table_B`'s primary key column.

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple elements where object_id: 4066, term_taxonomy_id: 5302, and since those are you're primary key they cannot be duplicated, consider changing your query to return unique values only.